# Is there a way to define the height and width of my Nivo slider?

Tags: html, css, nivo-slider

I want my nivo slider to have a height of 720px, that means the images in the slider will clip accordingly.

```
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider nivo-box">
      <img src="images/beach.jpg" />
      <img src="images/beach2.jpg" />
      <img src="images/beach3.jpg" />
      <img src="images/beach4.jpg" />
      <img src="images/beach5.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to override the styles in the #slider div but it didn't work, these are my custom styles:

```
#slider{
    height: 720px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Nivo Slider inherits the width of its parent container. At this time there is no setting within the admin to adjust the width. However, you can easily add some CSS to make this change.

To resize your Nivo slider, you will simply need to set the desired height to its container DIV, which is .slider-wrapper. You would want to add the following CSS into your design:

```
 .slider-wrapper {
    height: 720px;
}
```

Source: http://www.corecommerce.com/kb/89177/how_do_i_change_the_size_of_the_nivo_slider
Source: http://www.oik-plugins.com/wordpress-plugins-from-oik-plugins/wordpress-plugins/oik-nivo-slider/oik-nivo-slider-faq/controlling-the-height-of-the-nivo-slider/